# Share weights among layers in TensorFlow 2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-probability

I am trying to ascertain how one would go about sharing weights among a number of copies of a particular type of layer that are for instance stacked in a sequential Keras model, when using Tensorflow 2.0

Specifically from TensorFlow probability a `tfp.layers.VariationalGaussianProcess` layer. One of its inputs is a `kernel_provider` (which you make by subclassing a Keras layer).

What I would like to do is use a `tfp.positive_semidefinite_kernels.MaternOneHalf` kernel, which has amplitude and `length_scale` weights. Then for all the `VariationalGaussianProcess` layers in the model, for the amplitude and `length_scale` weights to be shared across all these layers.